# How can I quickly gain experience using animals?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I'm in need of a lot of XP for enchantment levels. I'm playing in Survival Mode, but don't have a lot of animals around me.
Is there a way to farm animals? And how can I find more animals?

Comment: Thx Tobtob1987 that helped a lot

Comment: So I'm confused. Did you want to get XP to enchant or breed/find more animals? This question is vague at best. If one of the answers helped you then you should accept it then btw.

Comment: Hey, Minecrafter. If it helped you, you should probably mark the answer as accepted by clicking the little tick icon under the vote count.

Comment: @Awesomeminecrafter - Um, just to clarify, are you looking for experience, or animals?

Comment: @Robotnik And still, not clear whether XP or animals is the goal  :) (after your edits)

Comment: @ydobonebi - Of course :). We're not supposed to change the meaning behind the author's question/answer, thus I had no way of telling what they actually wanted: it seems to be equally split between the two questions :/. In either case, both Tobtob1987's and KathyW.'s answers seem to cover it fairly well.

Comment: It seems quite clear to me that the question is how to find/breed a lot of animals in order to get a lot of Exp for enchanting.

Comment: I've edited the questions to be more straightforward, and to accommodate the answers (especially Kathy's, since hers is the most upvoted). I realize this might go against SE policy, but I'm sure the OP won't mind.

Answer (score 5):

**Getting Experience**

There are many ways to gain experience, but no matter what, it's going to take a bit of time. You could try several things, such as:

**Killing things** - You get experience for killing pretty much anything, with the exception of baby animals, bats, golems, and villagers. Notably, killing the ender dragon gives 12k XP, but it does take a bit of effort to pull that off. Okay, a lot of effort.

**Mining and Smelting** - You get experience for mining things that drop gems (diamonds, redstone, coal, emeralds), and experience for smelting anything (ores, wood, food, etc.). Also, if you find a monster spawner and mine that, you could get 15-43 XP.

**Breeding animals** - This kinda goes back to your question about farming animals. You can put animals into "love mode" by feeding the appropriate food to them (meat for dogs, fish for cats, etc.) and they will breed. There is a recharge period, but this is a fairly efficient way of producing XP, and you also get a ton of animals.

**Trading and Fishing** - Two other ways of gaining XP.

Keep in mind that the number of XP points needed to level up increases exponentially, so it would be easier to gain some levels, enchant, then repeat, rather than gain all your levels at once. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

- One of the best tactics is to **search for a [Dungeon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dungeon) or an [Abandoned Mineshaft](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Abandoned_mine_shaft)**.
  These contain monster spawners that constantly spawn monsters that you can kill over and over again to grind XP.
  Be careful - if you die you will always lose a large chunk of exp, even if you go back to pick up your things. Be sure to bring (at the very least) *a full set of iron armour* and an *iron sword*.
  If you are further into the game, *diamond armour*, a *diamond sword*, *potions of regeneration, healing and strength*, and *milk* (for poison) are all extremely useful items.
- Alternatively, **go to the Nether and find a [Nether Fortress](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_fortress)**.
  If you explore it you should come across a Blaze Spawner which acts in the same way as the other mob spawners (but is easier to find).
  Be careful though, blazes are dangerous. Make sure to bring plenty of long lasting [*Fire Resistance Potions*](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Potions_with_positive_effects) to fight the blazes with.
- If you don't fancy mob grinding, **search underground for coal and redstone**. They are both fairly common ores that give XP when mined (there are other ores that do this too, but they aren't as common).
- **Animal farming is extremely inefficient for XP gain** - it will take you a long time to get to level 30 using that method.
  However, if you aren't well equipped enough to fight large numbers of mobs yet, it can be useful for generating some XP.
- Also, **smelting large amounts of material in the furnace** will give you small XP boosts.

Comment: In terms of XP produced vs Rarity, You'd be better off looking for diamonds for XP than mob spawners. You find at average 3 per vein (I typically find more but this is what I"ve heard) and they give give average 5xp per block, so about 15 per average vein (more or less). Spawners will average something like 25 per but are about 9 times more rare in comparison. As for blaze, they are limited in terms of spawn area and spawn rate and cost to even safely kill, pigmen produce more XP and are many times more abundant. Cost to kill, 1 sword, 2 building blocks....

Comment: @ydobonebi That's entirely untrue. Abandoned mineshafts can be found fairly easily just by exploring, and produce an infinite fountain of XP

Answer (score 0):

In terms of rarity vs experience produced your best and fastest way, without a farm, is to go to the nether and mine nether quartz. Nether quartz drops 3-5 xp per, and is not very rare. Although things like diamonds produce more experience, their rarity makes them not a viable source. I have leveled to 30 in small about of time using this technique.

In terms of bravery, again in the nether you want to kill Zombie Pigmen. They drop the most amount of experience for rarity. You can easily find an area with a lot of Pigmen, or make a run thru some after pissing one off. Then just pillar up 2 blocks and hit them with your sword until they're clear.

Sources:

- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience

Comment: I was going to post the link for XBox360 XP and rarity, but the ads on the site are too close to porn and therefor not appropriate.

Comment: I disagree that Zombie Pigmen are the best choice - blazes can be killed infinitely (as they have a mob spawner) and if you use fire resistance potions they are easy to kill. Plus, they do less damage than pigmen and spawn in smaller numbers. You can also escape from blazes more easily than pigmen, and if you attack one group of pigmen, **all** pigmen will attack you, whereas blazes are only located in one area.

Comment: @imulsion pigmen spawn infinitely as well, without a spawner. More spawns, more area, less waiting between spawns, no automation required, but is possible and with no potion are easier to kill than blazes... Escaping is trivial with pigmen as well, just tower up 2 blocks and kill all the pigmen that approach you, if you can't bring extra blocks and tower higher up and wait 20 mins for them to forgive you. (or bridge somewhere)

Comment: in terms of difficulty, pigmen and blaze have same health, pigmen have 1 more strength (which they won't ever get to use if you just have 2 blocks)

Comment: But as I said, fire resistance potions make blaze fights trivial

Comment: and as I said, 2 blocks makes pigmen fighting trivial....and last I checked, 2 randome (i don't know....lets just say netherrack) blocks are easier, faster to acquire than a potion that requires you find either blaze already and slimes or just magma cube. I'd be able to level faster and sooner than you every single time.

Comment: But the fire resistance potions are easily acquired - even without them blazes are not difficult. Finding pigmen means traversing long distances -  usually over treacherous terrain - which can have any number of consequences including losing your portal and getting stuck. With blazes you can remain in one place and just grind for XP - bring 10 obsidian with you and you get a direct passage to XP. Even then (since OP seems fairly early on in the game) dungeons and abandoned mineshafts are far, far better than the nether - I doubt OP will be at the stage in the game where he can go there.

Comment: Even if he did, fighting blazes or cave spiders is far more efficient than mining ore or searching for pigmen

Comment: Searching for pigmen? Who searches for pigmen? Just walk thru a portal and you find them. I would,if I could, wager a petty 100 rep that starting with only a portal,  diamond sword that I would hit 30 levels, use them all and get 15 more before you any day.  As for mineshafts, besides normal ore which is just as common as non mineshaft areas, I would still hit level 30 first  if I started you in a mineshaft.

Comment: I can barely believe what I'm reading. Pigmen appear in clusters of 7 or 8, which means when you've killed them you have to **search for more**. I simply don't believe that you would level faster by your method as opposed to mine - blaze spawners are an infinite fountain of XP, which you can farm at your leisure - and in the long run, generate more XP more quickly.

Comment: Also there is absolutely no doubt in my mind that mob spawners generate more XP than ore - to suggest otherwise is ridiculous

Comment: @imulsion You are right, 15-75 per spawner vs 12 for a pigmen. If you adjust that for rarity mobs are always a better source (except maybe nether quart or diamonds) If you deal with ores you have to adjust for average vein size as well as spawn rarity. Spawners only have 1 per...well vein. Pigmen are easily killable as are blaze, but spawn over a larger area than blaze and produce more xp...adjust for spawn rate/rarity. I'll give you free fire resist potion, pigmen are still better. Straight by the numbers, not opinion at all. Endermen may be the only competition due to spawn rate in the end.

Comment: I didn't think of the endermen - but I suppose if you were at that point XP grinding wouldn't really be necessary...

Comment: @imulsion Talking strictly no automation is what I took the question to be. I took it to be, "I have no XP, I have enchant table, I want to have 30 levels sooner than later. I don't want my animals to die or breeding is too slow"

Answer (score -2):

There is no real fast way to farm animals. When you find a couple of them you might want to make a pen for them out of fence and lure them in.

- Pigs, and cows can be lured by wheat.
- Chickens are lured by grass seeds.

Then use the same food type to breed them and once you have a bunch, then you can kill all but two of them. Then boom, infinite exp.

Answer (score -3):

Mining is an effective way to gain experience, quickly.